# Android custom action bar occasionally displays a visual glitch

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat, android-actionbaractivity

I'm using a custom [support] action bar, but sometimes it displays a visual glitch:

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
        // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
        // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
        // this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
}

    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar_main);
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(actionBar.getCustomView().getBackground());
```

And in `action_bar_main.xml`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="50dp"
android:background="@color/myColor"
android:id="@+id/actionBarViewRoot">
...</FrameLayout> //I don't think inside is relevant, and it unnecessarily long.
```

Here is what I (and many other users with many different devices) *sometimes* get this visual glitch where blue background doesn't cover the whole action bar:

[image]

It just happens occasionaly, quite rarely, but it does happen, and I want to make sure it never happens. The seemingly-random nature of the problem makes it even harder to reproduce and test the issue. It doesn't appear to be bound to a specific make, model, or Android version. What are the possible causes?

Comment: I think this is due to the background color did you tried assigning same color android:background="@color/myColor" to all the elements in the layout ?

Comment: @Darkie Well, the main container layout has the background color, and as seen on the screenshot above, it's not from any of the views inside the action bar.

Comment: ok but the same problem occurred with me and I assigned the color to all the children of the parent layout and it did solve my problem.

Comment: @Darkie I'll be trying that. Though I don't really think that I can verify the problem has been solved in any means as it happens occasionaly.